# Hive - What is the purpose of CLIDriver.java?

Tags: hive

I am currently trying to understand the Hive codebase. What does org.apache.hive.cli.CLIDriver do? The class contains hardly any comments and the JavaDoc doesn't explain it either.

Answer (score 2):

The CLIDriver class in Hive is designed for starting a Hive session and reading the hiverc files if there is any, then loading the configurations from it and also processing the ; terminated commands that we execute in Hive

Thanks,
Achyut